# Using VBA in Excel to write newly created spreadsheets into a master spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, import

Currently we have files that get generated daily they use the same standard form however the amount of rows (corresponding to the amount of pallets we have) varies from day to day. I need to pull the information from each of these newly created spreadsheets into a master spreadsheet. I would like it so that when we enter in the Lot # (also the file name of the newly created worksheets) it pulls that data from the spreadsheet into the appropriate columns and row for however many pallets we have. If anyone could provide me a solution to this or at least point me in the right direction for a proper step-by-step tutorial i would appreciate it greatly. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Can you describe your "standard form" or the layout of your "master sheet"?

Comment: Try recording a macro while manually opening a file and copying the content.  See if you can modify what gets generated to make it more useful.  Post back with code if you're having problems getting it to work.

Comment: Tim Williams, Thanks a bunch that definitely got me moving into the right direction. I'm a bit of a VBA noob (pardon my gamer talk) I think following up from here I'd be a bit more able to do what I want. Thanks again.